# Knowledge we pass / give / transfer / convey further?

Tags: word-choice, idiomatic-language

When talking about **knowledge** which verb is more idiomatic and sounds more natural with it?

> I'll **pass** my knowledge to you, my students.
>
> We **pass** our knowledge (further) to the next generations.

or

> I'll **convey** my knowledge to you, my students.
>
> We **convey** our knowledge (further) to the next generations.

or

> I'll **give** my knowledge to you, my students.
>
> We **give** our knowledge (further) to the next generations.

or

> I'll **transfer** my knowledge to you, my students.
>
> We **transfer** our knowledge (further) to the next generations.

?

Comment: Who did downvote it?  Maybe I can explain for what's wrong with this question? (I saw that the answer of Roland Sole downvoted as well. What's wrong with his answer?).

Answer (score 1):

All of your verb choices are fine. There is no special difference between them in the context of knowledge. If you have a specific intended connotation, you can choose based solely on the different verb definitions.

Answer (score 0):

While your examples are grammatically correct, I don't think that any of them are idiomatic.

I should suggest **share knowledge with**, an expression that proves some 20 times more popular on Google Books Ngram viewer than **pass knowledge to**.

Similarly both **convey knowledge to** and **give knowledge to** get minimal returns on the Ngram Viewer. **Transfer knowledge to** does slightly better although I suggest that **transferring anything** from A to B signifies that A no longer has it.